# Is it possible to run node app alongside prestashop instance on the same VM?

Tags: node.js, prestashop, cpanel

I want to run nodeJS app which sole purpose is just to make some redirects based on DB queries, the app resides on main domain let's say `example.com`.

On a subdomain `shop.example.com` there is a prestashop 1.7 installed.

The virtual server software is cPanel.

Prestashop instance works as long as I don't install the node app, when I do it seems to make both `example.com` and `shop.example.com` unresponsive, and after a while it returns 503. The node app runs on port 8080.

Comment: When you say "based on DB queries", how do you capture these DB queries? Do you use the url to differentiate between the queries?

Comment: @BahaEddineAyadi actually the node app connects with the firebase instance. when the url is in the format `example.com/aS7vXbSDn9` it should ask the DB if an entry with that ID is present and redirect based on that entry value

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a .htaccess file that will redirect requests to the nodejs app. So inside your public_html, create a file named ".htaccess" and put this in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

And you should make request to this link instead : http://example.com/api/aS7vXbSDn9

The htaccess will redirect any request which contains /api to the nodejs app and pass whatever comes after the api/ to the app as a url paremeter.

For more information about htaccess, you can refer to this [link](http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=869&nav=0,46)

You can add these two lines as well (Before RewriteRule):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will make sure you only redirect request made for the api, not requests made to access files or directories.

Comment: Is there no possibility to have the app operate directly on root instead of `/api/ID` ? these links are encoded into QR codes, and hence should be shortest as possible

Comment: The /api is to make sure that the request will go through the nodejs app. If you want, you can try it without the /api and specify the RewriteCond that I gave you.

Comment: OK I tried these configurations:
```<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P]
</IfModule>```
and
```<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?$ https://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P]
</IfModule>```

with and without this:
```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d```

but the server still returns 503.

I wonder if the fact that something called Passenger and its configuration is also in this .htaccess? (seems like it's node app related)

Comment: there is also this:
```<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>```